# how to put text at bottom of div that is inside another div

Tags: html, css

I have the following layout:
[image]

and I want to put some text at bottom of div2 just like in the pic.

I have the following code:

```html
<style>
        .grey_box {
            background-color: grey;
            width: 680px;
            height: 500px;
        }
        .yellow_box {
            background-color: yellow;
            width: 450px;
            height: 300px;
        }


    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="grey_box">
        <div class="yellow_box">
            <h1>when I say div</h1>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `display: flex;` and  `align-items: flex-end;` to `.yellow-box`. See the snippet below:

```html
<style>
        .grey_box {
            background-color: grey;
            width: 680px;
            height: 500px;
        }
        .yellow_box {
            display: flex;
            align-items: flex-end;
            background-color: yellow;
            width: 450px;
            height: 300px;
        }


    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="grey_box">
        <div class="yellow_box">
            <h1>when I say div</h1>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: You could also position the text absolutely if you prefer. Simply add "position: relative;" to .yellow_box and then add a new selector targeting the h1, such as ".yellow_box h1" and apply the following styles to the h1: "position: absolute; left: 0; bottom: 0;"

Comment: ok that is fine, but for a beginner like me, at this stage, is there any means to achieve that without using flex?

Comment: @user221459 You can position the text absolutely if you'd like, as I commented above, however, flex is the easiest way to do this. Flex is incredibly helpful and quite simple to use once you learn it. If you're new to web development, I encourage you to learn it as soon as possible. It will save you a lot of headaches down the road given how popular and well-supported it has become across browsers.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure as per your little drawing that you made if the h1 is needed to be inside of the inner div like your code suggests, but your drawing does not.  If its not needed inside that inner div You can simply move the header text outside of the child div like this example.  But otherwise if you want the text at the bottom of the inner div, and not outside of it then you can follow the answer provided by @thenomadicmann

```css
     .grey_box {
            background-color: grey;
            width: 680px;
            height: 500px;
        }
        .yellow_box {
            background-color: yellow;
            width: 450px;
            height: 300px;
        }
```

```html
<div class="grey_box">
        <div class="yellow_box">
        </div>
        <h1>when I say div</h1>
    </div>
```

Comment: No this bit (<h1>when I say div</h1>) should be inside div 2, but on top, and <h1> you say tag</h1> should be inside div1, but bellow div 2